# Unknown character in beginng of html

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-2

I Use codeigniter to generate html.

At the beginning of each html
the character < is added in the beginning.

What could I do to fix that ?

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Search candidate</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: somehwhere you have an extra `<` symbol,are you inlcluding any other file before this

Comment: the answer below is probably correct, so you can use an text editor like notepad++ and remove that BOM character.

Answer (score 1):

A BOM character U+FEFF, a redundant zero-width space.

A BOM character is totally unnecessary, but is useed as first character in a Unicode text, to let the text be recognizable as UTF-8 (or UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE). Especially under Windows to let Nodepad distinguish it from the ANSI encoding of that system.

To remove the BOM, depends a bit on the editor. Maybe a simple delete will do. With a programmer's editor like JEdit or NotePad++ try a save as UTF-8 (without BOM). In a Java IDE you might try

Regex replace `"^."` with `""`.

Replace `"\ufeff"`".

Comment: +1 But please explain OP how to fix it (save without BOM) to make it a perfect answer.